# Regular expression for matching HH:MM:SS time format in php?

Tags: php, regex

what is the regular expression for HH:MM:SS

HH is hours , but not limited for day or clock it just can be any number from 0 to any integer

MM is minutes maximum is 59 and begin from 00

SS is Seconds maximum is 59 and begin from 00

Comment: the maximum is not 60, it is 59. it can never be 12:60:60.

Comment: @PlantTheldea yeah , The maximum is 59 I was worng, Thank you I will change it

Comment: @sectus but the hour maximum is not set , thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
([0-9]+):([0-5][0-9]):([0-5][0-9])
```

if the maximum is `59` (sensible). If you want `60` to also be possible,

```
([0-9]+):([0-5][0-9]|60):([0-5][0-9]|60)
```

EDIT: If you want the leading zero to be optional, the one in the comment works. This one is better tho:

```
([0-9]+):([0-5]?[0-9]):([0-5]?[0-9])
```

Comment: Yeah I was wrong the maximum is 59 , I will try your regex, Thank you

Comment: this work good, I just changed it to `([0-9]+):([0-9]+|59):([0-9]+|59)` to match 0:0:0 times ,

Comment: @Alsemany first off you said in your question you wanted it to be `00`. 2nd, your change will not give you what you expect. It will also match for `99:99:99`

Comment: what you really want then is `([0-9]+):([0-9]|[1-5][0-9]):([0-9]|[1-5][0-9])`

Comment: @Crayon Violent yeah , I don't know good about regex, I understand now that (|) mean (or) Thanks for help

Comment: after some search for regex and your notice I make this `(?:([0-9]+):|)([0-9]|[1-5][0-9]):([0-9]|[1-5][0-9])` to find the 59:59 and 111:59:59 times from the text and it work fine , please tell me if there's something wrong here !!